# Удаление ВСЕХ каналов на сервере

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Не совсем могу понять, куда что нужно написать, чтобы команда заработала.
Перепробовал много чего, но всё неудачно.

Та часть кода

```
@bot.command()
async def activate(ctx):
    channels = ctx.guild.channels
    delete = ctx.guildchannel.delete
    await delete(channels, reason = None)
```

Да, код писал сумасшедший, тобиш я, поэтому это нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@boy.command()
async def activate(ctx):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        await channel.delete()
```